# Why does Sinatra need to rewind the request body?

Tags: request, sinatra

I made a POST request to a Sinatra app. I noticed that the parameters arrive in the server as a StringIO. It can be read using `request.body.read`. However, it can only be read once. To read it again, I need to run `request.body.rewind` (haha, Sinatra).

Why is it designed this way? I can see this being useful in streaming data but are there other applications?

Comment: I wondered about this too from the [GitHub webhook example](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/securing/).

Answer (score 8):

Parameters are available within Sinatra via the params hash.  `request.body.read` and `request.body.rewind` are part of Rack, they are not actually implemented within Sinatra.  The most common way I have used this in the past is when I'm using Sinatra strictly as a web API and serializing/de-serializing my payload.

Comment: The question asks why: I'd like to read an answer (I voted up the question)

Comment: It's an IO object that gets buffered to a file and needs to be read in the order it was received for things like file uploads or streaming.  Also you have layers of rack middleware that possibly have read the body as well so you need to be able to get back to the beginning when needed.  A well behaved middleware would read then rewind.